# Grails: URL mapping with .gsp extension/format

Tags: grails, grails-controller, grails-3.3

I have a url request like `www.xyz.com/customer/list.gsp`

When I try to map the url to remove .gsp:

```
"/customer/list.gsp"(controller: "customer") {
        action = "list"
    }
```

grails application won't recognize the url and is throwing 404 error. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Update: apparently it is fine to map to GSPs.  I still think that the info below may be helpful so I'm leaving the answer up, but perhaps I have misunderstood your question.

Original response:

<strike>You shouldn't be mapping to or requesting gsps at all.  They're used to generate views, but are not viewable without rendering.</strike>

Instead, go to url like `www.xyz.com/customer/list` and map that like

```
"/customer/list" (controller: "customer") {
    action = "list"
}
```

Or even better, you don't need a custom mapping for each endpoint.  A default like this will work:

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?" { }
```

Your CustomerController will render the `list.gsp` in the `list` action.

Comment: "You shouldn't be mapping to or requesting gsps at all." - I don't agree with that.  We specifically support mapping urls to GSPs (the default `UrlMappings.groovy` file does that).  However, that isn't what the person in the question is doing.  They are including `.gsp` in the url, but are mapping to a controller action.  They are not mapping to a GSP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `.gsp` from the url then you can use a mapping like this...

```
"/customer/list"(controller: "customer") {
        action = "list"
}
```

You could also do this...

```
"/customer/list"(controller: "customer", action: "list")
```

If you want 1 mapping for all the actions in the controller, you could do this:

```
"/customer/$action"(controller: "customer")
```

The default generated mapping includes `"/$controller/$action"` which allows you map to any action in any controller.

With any of that, sending a request to `/customer/list` would work.